# How to pass arraylist to stored procedure in VB

Tags: vb.net

How to pass an ArrayList to the stored procedure in this code below

```
Dim sqlcon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connect").ConnectionString)
Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim arr As New ArrayList

arr.Add("@type,1") '--------------How do I pass this to my stored procedure
cmd = New SqlCommand("usp_demo", sqlcon)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
sda.SelectCommand = cmd

sda.Fill(dt)
```

---

Below is the Stored Procedure used - "usp_demo"

```
alter procedure usp_demo
@type int 
As
Begin

If @type = 1
Begin
select * from sample
End

If @type = 2
Begin
select * from nextnode
End
End
```

Comment: 1. Unless you have travelled back in time to before 2005, don't use an `ArrayList` in the first place. 2. You don't pass an `ArrayList` or any other list to a query as is. 3. If you'd like us to tell you how to do this properly, provide all the relevant information, i.e. show us the SQL code.

Comment: I'm guessing that there's no need for any list at all and you just need to add a single parameter named "@type" with the value 1, i.e. `cmd.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney -   "@type" with the value 1 is just a sample. I will be further needing to pass various control values or text as inputs to the procedure. So what would you suggest to use then?

Comment: I would suggest that you provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem in the question, as you should have in the first place.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have added the complete details of my code. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

The design of this code depends on how many parameters you need to pass. We don't want the user interface code worrying about the database so we don't want to create `SqlParameters` in the UI.  Let's say you have 5 parameters of different types. Just pass the values to the `Function`. If there are many parameters, create a class for the entity. Pass an instance of the class with the properties set in the UI code. You could even pass a `List(Of YourClass)` and loop through it resetting the .Value property of the Parameters.

Simple method as per your question.

```vb
Private Function GetData(type As Integer) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using sqlcon As New SqlConnection(),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("usp_demo", sqlcon)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.Int).Value = type
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        sqlcon.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Usage

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt = GetData(1)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

More than on parameter

```
Private Function InsertRecord(FName As String, LName As String) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connect").ConnectionString),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert Into Employee (FirstName, LastName) Values (@First, @Last);", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@First", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = FName
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Last", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = LName
        cn.Open()
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    End Using
    Return i
End Function
```

usage

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim i = InsertRecord("John", "Smith")
    If i = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Success")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Error")
    End If
End Sub
```

Create a class

```
Public Class Employee
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property MiddleName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property DOB As Date
    Public Property Weight As Integer
    Public Property Department As String
    Public Property IsHourly As Boolean
    Public Property Rate As Decimal

    Public Sub New(FName As String, MName As String, LName As String, Birth As Date, lbs As Integer, Dep As String, Hourly As Boolean, Pay As Decimal)
        FirstName = FName
        MiddleName = MName
        LastName = LName
        DOB = Birth
        Weight = lbs
        Department = Dep
        IsHourly = Hourly
        Rate = Pay
    End Sub
End Class
```

This class could probably be used other ways in your application.

```
Private Function InsertCompleteEmployee(e As Employee) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sql = "Insert Into EmployeeComplete (FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, DOB, Weight, Department, IsHourly, Rate) Values (@FName, @MName, @LName, @Birth, @lbs, @Dep, @Hourly, @Rate);"
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connect").ConnectionString),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@FName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = e.FirstName
            .Add("@MName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = e.MiddleName
            .Add("@LName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = e.LastName
            .Add("@Birth", SqlDbType.Date).Value = e.DOB
            .Add("@lbs", SqlDbType.Int).Value = e.Weight
            .Add("@Dep", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = e.Department
            .Add("@Hourly", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = e.IsHourly
            .Add("@Rate", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = e.Rate
        End With
        cn.Open()
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    End Using
    Return i
End Function
```

Usage

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim Emp As New Employee(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, DateTimePicker1.Value, 200, "Accountin", CheckBox1.Checked, 8.5D)
    Dim i = InsertCompleteEmployee(Emp)
    If i = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Success")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Error")
    End If
End Sub
```

The `Using...End Using` blocks ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed. In these Functions both the connection and the command are part of the block. Note the comma at the end of the Using line.

**Always use parameters** to avoid sql injection and make the sql string easier to write.

Answer (score -1):

Personally i generally use a key value pair [KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of SqlParameter))]; I hope that's what you were looking for; probably someone will have a better solution

```
Public Function ExecuteSelectionSP(ByVal MyConnectionString As String, ByVal KVP As KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of SqlParameter)), ByRef MyTable As DataTable) As Boolean
            Dim Result As Boolean
            Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection(MyConnectionString)
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = KVP.Key
            For Each MyParameter As SqlParameter In KVP.Value
                cmd.Parameters.Add(MyParameter)
            Next
            cmd.Connection = sqlcon
            Try
                If sqlcon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then sqlcon.Open()
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                MyTable.Load(reader)
                If sqlcon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then sqlcon.Close()
                Result = True
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Execution error :" & vbCrLf & KVP.Key & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Errore")
                Result = False
            End Try
            Return Result
        End Function
```

Comment: Why would your need to check connection state when you just created it a few lines above?

Comment: I guess if you have an error, you don't care if your connection is closed.

Comment: @Mary you don't. There are several things this answer does that are very wrong.

Comment: thanks Mary; except that I probably didn't answer the question; Could you point out what other things are wrong with my code Joel?